# Variable Does Not Update

Tags: python

So this is a model for a game I'm trying to make. the problem I'm having is happening between lines 68 - 75 I think. For some reason the NMHP or the mobHP are not updating. thankyou for any help

What I wanted to happen:

The function is supposed to be "Mobs Chi"(mchi) is less than "players chi"(phi) take the mobs health(mobHP) and subtract the Player damage from it the call NMHP. then I want the list out side of the function to be updated.

```
##ranbat.py
##make random battle for Player

##import random
##import time
##


def mobspawn():
    #imports
    import random
    import time
    #list,tup, and dicts
    plHP = ["30", "40", "50"]
    gchi = [".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"]
    pchi = [".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"]
    mchi = [".5", ".6", ".7", ".8", ".9"]
    dam = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60",]
    enList = ["Slime", "Goblin", "Hound", "NyaaTrape", "Navi"]
    enHP = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60",]
    enGen = ["he", "She", "it"]
    chiC = ["1", "2"]
    HELP = [("#", "Name", "Description"),("1", "Attack", "Attacks your enemy with equipped weapon"),("2", "Defend", "Use your equipped weapon to defend"),("3", "Heal", "If player has Med_Kit uses it on player"),("3", "Stats", "Prints players stats"),("5", "Finisher", "A secret technique (Has a 50% chance of a insta-kill)"),("6", "HELP", "This comand displays Help")]
    ########
    player = "Oni"
    ##############
    #Mob stats   #
    ##############
    Gen = random.choice(enGen)
    mobHP = random.randint(10, 60)
    mob = random.choice(enList)
    mdam = random.randint(10, 60)
    mchi = random.randint(1, 9)
    NMHP = 0
    mstat = [("HP","NMHP","Damage", "Chi"),(mobHP, NMHP, mdam, mchi)]
    ##############      
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Vofa: Oh no whats that!,", player, "protect me")
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)
    #print("here 2 ")
    print("You have incountered a wild", mob)
    print("")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Vofa: Looks like", Gen, "has",mobHP , "HP. Best be careful.")
    print("")
    ##############
    #Player stats#
    ##############
    plHP = random.randint(10, 60)
    pldam = random.randint(10, 60)
    pchi = random.randint(1, 9)
    plstat = [("HP","Damage", "Chi"),(plHP, pldam, pchi)]
    ##############
    batMenDis()       
    player=int(input())
    while player !=None:
        player = int(input())

        if player == 1:
            print("You have chosen option #1 Attack")
            print("You Attack")
            time.sleep(3)
            if (mchi) < (pchi):
                (NMHP) = (mobHP) - (pldam)
                (mobHP) = (NMHP)
                if mobHP < 0:
                    print( mob, "is dead")
                    break
                else:
                    print(mob,"Has",mobHP,"HP left")
            if (mchi) > (pchi):
                (NpHP) = (plHP) - (mdam)
                (pHP) = (NpHP)
                if plHP < 0:
                    print("you're almost dead. but you muster the strength to fight for a bit longer to keep vofa safe")
                    (pHP) = (pHP) + random.randint(1, 10)
                else:
                    print(player,"Has",plHP,"HP left")
            if (mchi) == (pchi):
                print("Both you and mob have the same amount of chi")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("")
                print("Coin has been tossed")
                chiC = random.choice(chiC)
                if chiC == 1:
                    mobHP = (mobHP) - (pldam)
                    print(mob,"Has",mobHP,"HP left")
                if chiC == 2:
                    pHP = (plHP) - (mdam)
                    print(player,"Has",plHP,"HP left")
        batMenDis()
        if player == 0:
            #print("here 2")
            print("You have chosen option number 0")
            print("Program Now Exiting")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Good Bye. Have a nice day! hope to fight with you again")
            break
def batMenDis():
    print("")
    print("What are you going to do")
    print("")
    print("1 = Attack")
    print("2 = Defend")
    print("3 = Heal")
    print("4 = Print current Stats")
    print("5 = Finisher (50% chance of working)")
    print("6 = HELP")
def main():
    mobspawn()
main()
```

Comment: This is not a minimal example; please reduce the code the what is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AdamSmith: No. First, `(spam)` is not a tuple; tuples always have commas. Second, wrapping both sides in a 1-tuple would have the same effect as wrapping neither (it would be a silly thing to do, but it wouldn't break things), while wrapping one side and not the other would (unless the right side happened to be some other kind of iterable) raise `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` or similar.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the correction. I still struggle with remembering all the intricacies of the language without pulling up an interpreter and trying it :)

Comment: I'm guessing the confusion is that you keep reusing the same variable names to mean different things. For example, `player` starts off as a string representing the player's name, then it becomes an integer representing the player's last menu choice; `mchi` starts off as a list of 5 strings representing what appear to be floats for some reason, then it becomes an integer representing the monster's chi stat. So, probably, whatever you thought one of those lines was supposed to be doing (which I can't guess), it's doing something completely different.

Comment: Another problem is that you do a lot of comparing integers and floats to the string representations of those integers and floats. For example, the first time you do `chiC = random.choice(chiC)`, you're going to get either the string `"1"` or the string `"2"`, neither of which is equal to either the number `1` or the number `2`, so neither of the two conditions is going to happen. (As a side note, you should look at `elif` and `else`, instead of trying to enumerate all of the branches as independent conditions that hopefully add up to covering everything.)

Comment: The whole thing (and this is my complaint about most of these "Debug my non-adventure text game" posts on here) would be better-suited to OOP. Make a `Monster` ABC, create individual types of `Monster`s with their own class, make a `Player` class that knows how to fight those monsters, and a `Menu` class that knows how to talk to the user, then build a `Game` class that knows how to receive input from your `Menu` and give direction to your `Player` and tie the whole shebang together. This is something I could help with in about an hour, if you're available

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not between lines 68 - 75:

```
if (mchi) < (pchi):
    (NMHP) = (mobHP) - (pldam)
    (mobHP) = (NMHP)
    if mobHP < 0:
        print( mob, "is dead")
        break
    else:
        print(mob,"Has",mobHP,"HP left")
```

beacause when you get in there, your damage is always bigger than the monster's HP (HP is 1-9 and damage is 10-60). The result is therefore always the monster getting killed.

But if we look at the other branch:

```
if (mchi) > (pchi):
    (NpHP) = (plHP) - (mdam)
    (pHP) = (NpHP) # error here, should be plHP
    if plHP < 0:
        print("you're almost dead. but you muster the strength to fight for a bit"
              "longer to keep vofa safe")
        (pHP) = (pHP) + random.randint(1, 10) # same here
    else:
        print(player,"Has",plHP,"HP left")
```

You are not substracting damage from plHP, but pHP (which is not defined up until then). That way, the plHP stays always the same.